# Restricting user to enter only 1/2/3 as input in perl

Tags: perl

What is the slickest way to programmatically read either 1 / 2 / 3 as input for one argument in Perl ?

Comment: one way would be, if($input =~ /[^1-3]/ )

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can try this code:

```
do {$i = <>} while ($i !~ /^[123]$/);
print $i;
```

This code reads from stdin to variable $i, until input value is 1 / 2 / 3.
Then it prints it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why do you say "This does not provide an answer to the question"? It does... If somebody have a slicker way to the problem, post it, and I'll vote for it, too... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS if you want it to be an answer than you have to explain it more briefly.

Comment: @Marcos, one more, sorry for that. I want this in a loop so that until either of this inputted it never ends.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not the *slickest* way, but yeah, it is fairly simple and straight forward and it works.

Code:

```
$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input=$ARGV[0];
print $input."\n" if $input =~ /^1$|^2$|^3$/;
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl 1
1
$ perl test.pl 2
2
$ perl test.pl 3
3
$ perl test.pl 12
$ perl test.pl 21
$ perl test.pl 13
$ perl test.pl 31
$ perl test.pl 4
$ perl test.pl 5
$ perl test.pl 11
$ perl test.pl 22
$ perl test.pl 33
$
```

You may further customize this code to ensure that an input is mandatory else the script should print usage  of script or something similar.